# A 2013-14 show about youth with elemental monsters that aired on Teletoon or Cartoon Network

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

The main character, a boy had a fire monster and his friends all had different monsters with different elements. In the finale the boy convinced a giant fire monster (I think they were titans or something) to help him fight the villain, who awakened a water titan. The main character's friends also woke up a giant turtle with a mountain on his back (the earth titan). I watched it in 2012-2014. I saw the Polish dubbing of it so the time it could be even earlier.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)